# "expected type parameter, found struct"

Tags: rust

I've been messing around with traits using Rust and I've come across a problem. Here's some code:

```
struct Foo;

trait Bar {}

impl Bar for Foo {}

fn bar<B: Bar>(bar: B) {}

fn barr<B: Bar>() {
    bar(Foo); // 1. THIS WILL WORK
    let foo: B = Foo; // 2. THIS WILL NOT WORK
    let foo_vec: Vec<B> = vec![Foo]; // 3. THIS WILL NOT WORK
}
```

This produces the errors:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:11:18
   |
11 |     let foo: B = Foo; // 2. THIS WILL NOT WORK
   |                  ^^^ expected type parameter, found struct `Foo`
   |
   = note: expected type `B`
              found type `Foo`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:12:32
   |
12 |     let foo_vec: Vec<B> = vec![Foo]; // 3. THIS WILL NOT WORK
   |                                ^^^ expected type parameter, found struct `Foo`
   |
   = note: expected type `_`
              found type `Foo`
```

Why won't #2 & #3 work? How can I let the compiler know that `Foo` does in fact have a `Bar` `impl`?

---

Another examle:

```
struct Foo<B: Bar> {
    bar: Option<B>,
}

struct Foo2;

trait Bar {}

impl<B: Bar> Bar for Foo<B> {}

impl Bar for Foo2 {}

fn bar<B: Bar>(bar: B) {}

fn circle_vec<B: Bar>() {
    bar(Foo2); // 1. WORKS
    Foo { bar: Some(Foo { bar: None }) }; // 2. WILL NOT WORK
}
```

This will give me this error:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:17:21
   |
17 |     Foo { bar: Some(Foo { bar: None }) }; // 2. WILL NOT WORK
   |                     ^^^ cannot infer type for `B`
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have two different problems so I guess I'll write two different answers.

---

In your first code sample, 2 and 3 don't work because B is an *input* type parameter; it is the caller of `barr` that decides what B is. However, you are trying to force it to be `Foo`.

Let's suppose we have another implementation of `Bar`:

```
struct Quux;

impl Bar for Quux {}
```

And let's suppose we call `barr` like this:

```
barr::<Quux>()
```

`barr` would essentially be compiled as this:

```
fn barr() {
    bar(Foo);
    let foo: Quux = Foo;
    let foo_vec: Vec<Quux> = vec![Foo];
}
```

`Foo` and `Quux` are not compatible, and `Vec<Foo>` and `Vec<Quux>` are not compatible either.

If you're trying to create a vector of arbitrary `Bar` objects, you need to use `Bar` in a non-generic way. As trait types are unsized, you can't store them directly in a `Vec`, so you must use `Vec<Box<Bar>>`, `Vec<&Bar>` or some other type that wraps a pointer.

```
fn barr() {
    bar(Foo);
    let foo: Box<Bar> = Box::new(Foo);
    let foo_vec: Vec<Box<Bar>> = vec![Box::new(Foo) as Box<Bar>];
}
```

---

In your second code sample, the error is that `None` has the type `Option<T>`, and the compiler is unable to infer an appropriate type for `T`. We can explicitly specify `T` like this:

```
fn circle_vec<B: Bar>() {
    bar(Foo2);
    Foo {
        bar: Some(Foo { bar: None::<Foo2> }),
    };
}
```

Comment: One last question, why won't `fn barr<B: Bar>() { let foo_vec: Vec<Box<B>> ...}` work? Or can it work and I'm just missing something?

Comment: By using a type parameter, all the elements of your vector must be of the same type, specified by the caller, which means you can't store a Foo in the vector because `B` might not be `Foo`. To add elements to the vector, you need values of type `B`, which you'd generally receive as parameters to the function (`fn barr<B: Bar>(x: B)`).

Comment: This seems to be using trait objects, i.e. dynamic dispatch. However, [the Rust Programming Language book on this topic](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/trait-objects.html) says "one can always have a thin statically-dispatched wrapper function that does a dynamic dispatch, but not vice versa, meaning static calls are more flexible." Is there actually a way to not use trait objects and only perform static dispatch in this case? I also encountered the use case where I want to have a vector storing potentially different types of structs implementing the same trait.