# Rust generics/traits: "expected 'Foo<B>', found 'Foo<Foo2>'"

Tags: rust

I asked a similar [question earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049939/expected-type-parameter-found-struct/26050207) which has helped me understand what is going on *under the hood* but I still can not get Rust to do what I want it to do when it comes to generic programming. Here's some code:

```
struct Foo<B: Bar> { bars: Vec<Box<B>> }

struct Foo2;

trait Bar {}

impl Bar for Foo2 {}

impl<B: Bar> Foo<B> {
  fn do_something() -> Foo<B> {
    let foo2:Box<Bar> = box Foo2;
    let mut foo = Foo { bars: vec!(box Foo2) };
    foo.bars.push(box Foo2);
    foo // compiler: *ERROR*
  }
}
```

Error: `expected 'Foo<B>', found 'Foo<Foo2>'`

1. How can I give the compiler a *hint* or explicitly tell the compiler that `foo` (`Foo`) implements `Bar` (`B: Bar`)?
2. Is this a bug? Should I just hold off on using Rust until it reaches 1.0?

version: `0.12.0-nightly (4d69696ff 2014-09-24 20:35:52 +0000)`

---

Problems I see with @Levans' solution:

```
struct Foo2;

struct Foo3 {
  a: int
}

trait Bar {
    fn create_bar() -> Self;
}

impl Bar for Foo2 {
    fn create_bar() -> Foo2 { Foo2 } // will work
}

impl Bar for Foo3 {
    fn create_bar(a: int) -> Foo3 { Foo3 {a: a} } // will not work
}
```

Error: `method 'create_bar' has 1 parameter but the declaration in trait 'Bar::create_bar' has 0`

Also, I noticed this: `Bar::create_bar()`. How would Rust know to use `Foo2`'s implementation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you define a function using `<B: Bar>` you're telling the compiler "you can replace in this function `B` by any type implementing the trait `Bar`".

For example, if you created a struct `Foo3` implementing trait `Bar` as well, the compiler would expect to be able to call `do_something` with `B` being `Foo3`, which is not possible with your current implementation.

In your situation, your `do_something` function attempts to create a `B` object, it thus needs a generic way to do so, given by the `Bar` trait, as a `create_bar()` method for example, like this :

```
struct Foo<B: Bar> { bars: Vec<Box<B>> }

struct Foo2;

trait Bar {
    fn create_bar() -> Self;
}

impl Bar for Foo2 {
    fn create_bar() -> Foo2 { Foo2 }
}

impl<B: Bar> Foo<B> {
  fn do_something() -> Foo<B> {
    let mut foo = Foo { bars: vec!(box Bar::create_bar()) }; 
    foo.bars.push(box Bar::create_bar());
    foo 
  }
}
```

---

**Answer to edit :**

In your code, it indeed won't work because you expect to pass more arguments to `create_bar`, which is not possible as it does not respect the trait definition that `create_bar` does not take any arguments.

But something like this would work without any problem :

```
struct Foo2;

struct Foo3 {
  a: int
}

trait Bar {
    fn create_bar() -> Self;
}

impl Bar for Foo2 {
    fn create_bar() -> Foo2 { Foo2 }
}

impl Bar for Foo3 {
    fn create_bar() -> Foo3 { Foo3 {a: Ou} }
}
```

The point is : your `do_something` function cannot create `Bar` objects without a generic way of doing so, a way that would not depend on which type is in `<B>`, provided it implements `Bar`. That's how generics work : if you call `do_something::<Foo2>()`, it's exactly as if you replaced `B` by `Foo2` in the whole definition of your function.

Yet, I suspect what you really are trying to do is store *differents* types, all implementing `Bar` in the same Vec, (otherwise wrapping a Box inside would be quite useless), you can achieve this with trait objects, and it does not require generics :

```
struct Foo<'a> { bars: Vec<Box<Bar + 'a>> }

struct Foo2;

trait Bar {}

impl Bar for Foo2 {}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
  fn do_something() -> Foo<'a> {
    let mut foo = Foo { bars: vec!(box Foo2 as Box<Bar>) };
    foo.bars.push(box Foo2 as Box<Bar>);
    foo
  }
}
```

Basically, Trait objects are references or pointers to objects, casted as Trait :

```
let foo2 = Foo2;
let bar = &foo2 as &Bar; // bar is a reference to a Trait object Bar
```

And as provided in my example, it works with Boxes as well.

Comment: I foresee problems with this solution. What if I have many different structs implementing `Bar` but have different fields? See my edit above to see an example

Comment: I sort of figured that's what the problem is. Thanks. Also, your code as is will not compile. err: `explicit lifetime bound required`