# "Expected type parameter" error in the constructor of a generic struct

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I am trying to store piston textures in a struct.

```
struct TextureFactory<R> where R: gfx::Resources {
    block_textures: Vec<Rc<Texture<R>>>,
}

impl<R> TextureFactory<R> where R: gfx::Resources  {
    fn new(window: PistonWindow) -> Self {
        let texture = Rc::new(gfx_texture::Texture::from_path(
            &mut *window.factory.borrow_mut(),
            "assets/element_red_square.png",
            Flip::None, &TextureSettings::new()
        ).unwrap());
        let block_textures = Vec::new();
        block_textures.push(texture);

        TextureFactory {
            block_textures: block_textures,
        }
    }
}
```

This does not compile:

```
src/main.rs:37:9: 39:10 error: mismatched types:
 expected `TextureFactory<R>`,
    found `TextureFactory<gfx_device_gl::Resources>`
(expected type parameter,
    found enum `gfx_device_gl::Resources`)
```

`gfx_device_gl::Resources` [implements `gfx::Resources`](http://www.piston.rs/docs/piston_window/gfx/device/trait.Resources.html) though (I think it's just the device specific implementation.) I don't actually care what type this is, but I need to know so that I can store it in the struct.

I made a [compilable repo on Github](https://github.com/xaviershay/rust-puzzlefighter/tree/repro).

(I suspect [Rust generics/traits: "expected 'Foo<B>', found 'Foo<Foo2>'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26063593/rust-generics-traits-expected-foob-found-foofoo2) is the same question, but I can't figure out how to apply it to my problem.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490913/rust-generics-expected-t-found-foo or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31060851/generics-error-expected-type-parameter-found-struct

Comment: You may use [trait objects](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/trait-objects.html), to achieve the kind of polymorphism your code seems to involve.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here's a reproduction of your error:

```
struct Foo<T> {
    val: T,
}

impl<T> Foo<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Foo { val: true }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

The problem arises because you tried to lie to the compiler. This code:

```
impl<T> Foo<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Says "For whatever `T` the **caller** chooses, I will create a `Foo` with that type". Then your actual implementation picks a *concrete type* — in the example, a `bool`. There's no guarantee that `T` is a `bool`. Note that your `new` function doesn't even accept any parameter of type `T`, which is highly suspect as that's how the caller picks the concrete type 99% of the time.

The correct way of saying this would be

```
impl Foo<bool> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Foo { val: true }
    }
}
```

Although you probably want to pick a more specific name than `new`, as it looks as if you are trying to make your struct generic. Presumably there would be *other* constructors with different types.

For your exact code, you probably want something like

```
impl TextureFactory<gfx_device_gl::Resources> { /* ... */ }
```

Another possible solution would be to remove the generic type parameter from your struct. If you only ever construct it with a `gfx_device_gl::Resources`, then there's no reason to make it generic.

In other cases, you may be trying to return a type that implements a trait. For that, you can use a boxed trait object:

```
impl Foo<Box<dyn std::fmt::Display>> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Foo { val: Box::new(true) }
    }
}
```

In the future, you may also be able to use `impl Trait` (a.k.a. *existential types*):

```
#![feature(type_alias_impl_trait)]

struct Foo<T> {
    val: T,
}

type SomeConcreteButOpaqueType = impl std::fmt::Display;

impl Foo<SomeConcreteButOpaqueType> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Foo { val: true }
    }
}
```

See also:

- [What is the correct way to return an Iterator (or any other trait)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423)

Comment: thank you! I didn't realise I could "specialise" things in `impl`.