# How can I store a generator in a struct?

Tags: types, rust, closures, generator

I want to do [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9958d96a64bcf526745c0bcc8aca779e&version=nightly&mode=debug):

```
#![feature(nll)]
#![feature(generators, generator_trait)]
use std::ops::Generator;

struct Container<G: Generator<Yield = i32, Return = ()>> {
    generator: G
}

impl<G: Generator<Yield = i32, Return = ()>> Container<G> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let q = 42;
        Container{ generator: || {
            yield 2i32 * q;
        } }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

I get this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:12:31
   |
   |           Container{ generator: || {
   |  _______________________________^
   | |             yield 2i32 * q;
   | |         } }
   | |_________^ expected type parameter, found generator
   |
   = note: expected type `G`
              found type `[generator@src/main.rs:12:31: 14:10 q:_ _]`
```

Thanks to ["Expected type parameter" error in the constructor of a generic struct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551177/155423) I'm a little closer, having removed the generic type after `impl` (since I'm not implementing the struct for arbitrary `G`. I tried these variations, none of which work:

```
impl Container<G> 
where
    G: Generator<Yield = i32, Return = ()>
{ /* ... */ }
```

```
impl Container<Generator<Yield = i32, Return = ()>> { /* ... */ }
```

```
impl Container<_> { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I found an answer, but if someone has a better one, feel free to post. I'm obviously not super knowledgeable about this yet or I wouldn't have asked.

For completeness: the generic `G` is needed because generators are like closures, and every closure has a different type (not just every declaration - every instantiation as well) because it captures a different environment.

As ["Expected type parameter" error in the constructor of a generic struct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551177/155423) pointed out, the first problem was the generic type after `impl`. That meant that the implementation was for an externally chosen `T`, but the `Self` returned instead had a specific value for the type parameter, namely the one of the generator.

As for how to replace it,

- `impl Container<G> where G: Generator<Yield = i32, Return = ()>`

  This does not work because although `G` is bounded (pretty strictly), there is still no one responsible for choosing the specific `G`.
- `impl Container<_>`

  This does not work because type inference does not work for struct implementations. Which probably makes sense - it wouldn't really be logical for anything but 'constructors'.
- `impl Container<Generator<Yield = i32, Return = ()>>`

  This does not work because `Generator` is a trait and trait objects are not sized (whereas this type parameter should be sized).

The sizedness thing can be resolved. It took a bit of trying and I'm not sure it's perfect, but adding a `Box` *at the implementation* fixed it. Note that the `Box` is not part of `Container`; apparently `Box<Generator<...>>` also satisfies the constraint `G: Generator<...>`?

I *think* it also greatly reduces the odds of the generator being moved, which I *think* should not happen:

> The function `resume` is unsafe because it can be used on an immovable generator. After such a call, the immovable generator must not move again, but this is not enforced by the compiler.

The complete code:

```
#![feature(nll)]
#![feature(generators, generator_trait)]

use std::ops::Generator;

struct Container<G>
where
    G: Generator<Yield = i32, Return = ()>,
{
    generator: G,
}

impl Container<Box<Generator<Yield = i32, Return = ()>>> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let q = 42;
        Container {
            generator: Box::new(move || {
                yield 1i32 * q;
                yield 2i32 * q;
                yield 3i32 * q;
            }),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Playground [for the above](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0b1ed644c4fca5256b785ac363c54d63&version=nightly&mode=debug) and [usage example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8504ef8102e6200a1331dc376d7a8589&version=nightly&mode=debug).

Comment: *apparently `Box<Generator<...>>` also satisfies the constraint `G: Generator<...>`* — [yes, as do references to generators](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Generator.html#implementors), just the same as iterators.

Answer (score 1):

A trick that isn't always applicable is to split the creation of the generator (or iterator, these are amazingly similar concepts) into a separate function. This allows you to use `impl Trait`:

```
fn container_core(q: i32) -> impl Generator<Yield = i32, Return = ()> {
    move || {
        yield 1 * q;
        yield 2 * q;
        yield 3 * q;
    }
}

impl<G> Container<G>
where
    G: Generator<Yield = i32, Return = ()>,
{
    pub fn new(generator: G) -> Self {
        Container { generator }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Container::new(container_core(42));
}
```

You still cannot name the type of `x` so you cannot store it in a struct, so the root problem is unsolved. Of course, you can combine the answers:

```
impl Container<Box<Generator<Yield = i32, Return = ()>>> {
    fn new_boxed(q: i32) -> Self {
        Container::new(Box::new(container_core(q)))
    }
}
```