# How can I specialize a function's return value?

Tags: generics, rust

The following block is library code; I can't edit it:

```
struct Container<F> {
    f: F,
}

fn wrapped<F, T>(f: F) -> Container<F>
where
    F: FnMut() -> T,
{
    Container { f }
}
```

I want a wrapper function that specializes `T`:

```
fn return_10() -> u32 {
    10
}

fn wrapper<F>() -> Container<F>
where
    F: FnMut() -> u32,
{
    wrapped(return_10)
}

fn main() {
    wrapper();
}
```

(For the sake of simplicity, I used `u32` in the code above, but in reality I want to use a trait. I'm hoping that this doesn't matter.)

It doesn't work:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:20:13
   |
20 |     wrapped(return_10)
   |             ^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter, found fn item
   |
   = note: expected type `F`
              found type `fn() -> u32 {return_10}`
```

Why can't Rust infer that `T = u32`? Am I supposed to not do this?

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [“Expected type parameter” error in the constructor of a generic struct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551177/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: TL;DR: `fn wrapper() -> Container<fn() -> u32> { wrapped(return_10) }` or `fn wrapper() -> Container<impl Fn() -> u32> { wrapped(return_10) }`

Comment: @Shepmaster Well, there's the issue that the `<impl Fn() -> T>` syntax does not seem to exist in the [manual](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch00-00-introduction.html) and I might have never have been able to find it if it weren't for the answers below...

Comment: @Shepmaster I did see that post and it did not help me; even now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write a function signature like this:

```
fn wrapper<F>() -> Container<F> 
where
    F: FnMut() -> u32;
```

It means:

> *For **any** type `F` that **you** choose, which implements `FnMut() -> u32`, I can give you a `Container<F>`.*

If that was the case then you would be able to define some arbitrary struct, and have it implement `FnMut() -> u32`, and the `wrapper` function would have to somehow be able to conjure up an instance of it. That would be impossible - unless the `FnMut` trait also had a method to create new instances.

But luckily your code is doing something different. Rather than working for *all* possible types `F`, you just need it to work for one - the one that you know you'll return.

The way to describe that is with an `impl Trait`:

```
fn wrapper() -> Container<impl Fn() -> u32> {
    wrapped(return_10)
}
```

It means:

> *I'm going to return a `Container<F>`. `F` will implement `Fn() -> u32` but **I'm** going to choose exactly what that concrete type is.*

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you're looking for but this code compiles.

```
struct Container<F> {
    f: F,
}

fn wrapped<F, T>(f: F) -> Container<F>
where
    F: FnMut() -> T,
{
    Container { f }
}

fn return_10() -> u32 {
    10
}

fn wrapper() -> Container<fn() -> u32> {
    wrapped(return_10)
}

fn main() {
    wrapper();
}
```

I figured this out by using the code below to force the compiler to spit out a message telling me the type it was expecting.

```
struct Container<F> {
    f: F,
}

fn wrapped<F, T>(f: F) -> Container<F>
where
    F: FnMut() -> T,
{
    Container { f }
}

fn return_10() -> u32 {
    10
}

fn main() {
    let x: () = wrapped(return_10);
}
```

When you compile the code above the compiler complains

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:17:17
   |
17 |     let x: () = wrapped(return_10);
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected (), found struct `Container`
   |
   = note: expected type `()`
              found type `Container<fn() -> u32 {return_10}>`
```

Comment: Interesting. But how did you know that you could get this suggestion by assigning the result of `wrapped()`? The original error was pointing to the argument... which does appear in the same line... but is also kind of... "unrelated"?

Comment: Ah, well, I knew there was an issue with the return type of `wrapper` which must be the same as the return type of `wrapped(return_10)`