# How do I push a trait type into a Vec?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to push items into a `VecDeque`, but I can't get my head around this bit. The compiler complains that my `push_back` method in the `InnerQueue` impl is a generic `T` type (well, it is). How can I fix the code so I can push `UserItem`s into a `User` typed `Queue`?

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;

fn main() {}

struct Queue<T: InnerQueue> {
    name: String,
    queue: T,
}

impl<T: InnerQueue> Queue<T> {
    pub fn new(name: String) -> Queue<T> {
        Queue {
            name,
            queue: T::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn push<R>(&self, data: R)
    where
        R: QueueItem,
    {
        self.queue.push_back(data);
    }
}

trait QueueItem {}

type UserItem = (u32, u64, u64);

impl QueueItem for UserItem {}

trait InnerQueue {
    fn new() -> Self;
    fn push_back<T: QueueItem>(&mut self, data: T);
}

type User = VecDeque<UserItem>;

impl InnerQueue for User {
    fn new() -> Self {
        VecDeque::new()
    }

    fn push_back<T: QueueItem>(&mut self, data: T) {
        self.push_back(data);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f480ddb54b21f0d840d7c57ac509ba42)

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:46:24
   |
45 |     fn push_back<T: QueueItem>(&mut self, data: T) {
   |                  - this type parameter
46 |         self.push_back(data);
   |                        ^^^^ expected tuple, found type parameter `T`
   |
   = note:       expected tuple `(u32, u64, u64)`
           found type parameter `T`
   = help: type parameters must be constrained to match other types
   = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#traits-as-parameters
```

Comment: You can probably use an associated type and do away with the `QueueItem` trait: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ebe418ae8b813b955bfae09c1717cac3

Comment: (Haven't thought about this properly, so not posting this as answer.)

Comment: Generally, it would help to think what would happen in your implementation of `push_back` was called multiple times for distinct `T` types. But more specifically, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53085270/1233251) shows a very similar problem.

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How do I create a heterogeneous collection of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27957103/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thanks, this seems to be working. I have to read about that `type Item` thing. @Shepmaster Thanks for the link, it explains it well!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a heterogeneous collection of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957103/how-do-i-create-a-heterogeneous-collection-of-objects)

Comment: @trentcl It looks like the OP isn't looking for a heterogeneous collection, but that's not really clear from the question.