# How to implement a trait function generic over return type

Tags: rust

```
trait CallOnceSafe {
    fn call_once_safe<R>(&mut self, x: &mut [u8]) -> smoltcp::Result<R>;
}

impl<R, F: FnOnce(&mut [u8]) -> smoltcp::Result<R>> CallOnceSafe for Option<F> {
    fn call_once_safe<R>(&mut self, x: &mut [u8]) -> smoltcp::Result<R> {
        // panics if called more than once - but A::consume() calls it
        // only once
        let func = self.take().unwrap();
        func(x)
    }
}
```

In this case, I cannot use `fn call_once_safe<R>` because `R` is already being used as a type parameter for the implementation of the trair.

How can I implement this trait function with a generic type R?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I implement a trait with a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53085270/how-do-i-implement-a-trait-with-a-generic-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `CallOnceSafe` is defined right now **the caller** of `call_once_safe` can choose `R`, while the implementer has to guarantee that no matter what `R` is choose, a `smoltcp::Result<R>` will be returned, however any implementation for `Option<F>` where `F: FnOnce(&mut [u8]) -> smoltcp::Result<R>` will only work for the specific `R` that `F` can return.

The only reasonable solution is to change how `CallOnceSafe` is defined. There are two way you can do this:

- Make `R` a generic type parameter. This will allow you to choose for which `R` you want to implement `CallOnceSafe<R>`.

```rust
trait CallOnceSafe<R> {
    fn call_once_safe(&mut self, x: &mut [u8]) -> smoltcp::Result<R>;
}

impl<R, F: FnOnce(&mut [u8]) -> smoltcp::Result<R>> CallOnceSafe<R> for Option<F> {
    fn call_once_safe(&mut self, x: &mut [u8]) -> smoltcp::Result<R> {
        // panics if called more than once - but A::consume() calls it
        // only once
        let func = self.take().unwrap();
        func(x)
    }
}
```

- Make `R` an associated type. This works because the implementor chooses what the associated types are. Note that I opted to call it `Ret` because with `R` it would have lead to a `type R = R;` which I think is a bit confusing (but is still totally valid code).

```rust
trait CallOnceSafe {
    type Ret;
    fn call_once_safe(&mut self, x: &mut [u8]) -> smoltcp::Result<Self::Ret>;
}

impl<R, F: FnOnce(&mut [u8]) -> smoltcp::Result<R>> CallOnceSafe for Option<F> {
    type Ret = R;
    fn call_once_safe(&mut self, x: &mut [u8]) -> smoltcp::Result<R> {
        // panics if called more than once - but A::consume() calls it
        // only once
        let func = self.take().unwrap();
        func(x)
    }
}
```

The difference between the two solutions is that the generic type parameter will allow the trait to be implemente multiple times for the same type, each time with a different `R`, while the associated type will only allow one `impl` for each type. This shouldn't matter if you're only planning to implement it for `Option<F>` and use it to reduce code duplication.