# How to fix error with generic function in rust

Tags: generics, rust

I am trying to understand generics in Rust. I am not able to get what went wrong here

```
fn say<T>(msg: &T)  {
    let slen = msg.chars().count();
    if slen > 0 {
        println!("Char Count {} " ,slen);
    } 
}


fn main() {
    let msg = String::from("Hello World from Rust!!!");
    say::<String>(&msg);
}
```

Compilation Error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `chars` found for reference `&T` in the current scope
 --> hell.rs:4:20
  |
4 |     let slen = msg.chars().count();
  |                    ^^^^^ method not found in `&T`
```

Comment: `say<T>` means that "for whatever `T`, this method will work." Arbitrary types aren't guaranteed to have a `chars` method, so the generic doesn't work here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. how to make this work.also isnt hinting of <String> while invoking function wont help ?

Comment: If your generic only works with a specific type, then it won't work. Just don't use a generic and take in `&str` instead.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53085270

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea behind Rust generics is that the generic types are both restricted and defined by *trait bounds*. A function generic over a `T` bound by a set of traits may assume that `T` has methods from those traits and no more. Since `T` is not bound by any trait, there is no `T::chars()` method to call.

To write generic code that invokes methods not provided by any existing traits, such as `chars()`, you can write your own trait that provides the needed functionality, and implement it for the types you need. For example:

```
trait CharCount {
    fn char_count(&self) -> usize;
}

impl CharCount for String {
    fn char_count(&self) -> usize {
        self.chars().count()
    }
}
```

With this trait you can write your generic method to make use of it:

```
fn say<T: CharCount>(msg: &T)  {
    let slen = msg.char_count();
    if slen > 0 {
        println!("Char count: {}", slen);
    } 
}
```

You can invoke `say` with `String`, but also with any other type that decides to implement the `CharCount` trait, even if it's a type you haven't envisioned while writing the trait.

Comment: its great coincidence by the time this answer came i too came to find similar solution. Accepting your solution as answer     ```trait Dummy {
    fn len(&self) -> usize;

}

impl Dummy for String {
    fn len(&self) -> usize {
        return self.chars().count();
    }
}

fn say<T: Dummy>(msg: T)  {
    let slen = msg.len();
    if slen > 0 {
        println!("Char Count {} " ,slen);
    } 
}


fn main() {
    let msg=String::from("Hello World from Rust!!!");
    say::<String>(msg);
}```

Answer (score 2):

Your function `say` assumes that the input has a `chars` method that creates an iterator over `chars`. There aren't many types that this would work for, so it doesn't seem very useful to make it generic.

The main two types that have a `chars` iterator method are `String` and `&str`. If you change the parameter to be `&str` then you can accept either one of them:

```
fn say(msg: &str)  {
    let slen = msg.chars().count();
    if slen > 0 {
        println!("Char Count {} ", slen);
    } 
}


fn main() {
    let msg: String = String::from("Hello World from Rust!!!");
    say(&msg);
    let msg: &str = "Hello World from Rust!!!";
    say(msg);
}
```

See also:

- [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-to-a-string-string-vec-vec-o)

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to play with generics / traits you could take a  `T: AsRef<str>`.

Comment: Thanks Peter for sharing link in reference to string that’s useful will keep in mind