# Pass struct generic type to trait generic method

Tags: rust

I have a trait

```
trait MyTrait {
    fn generic_method<T: OtherTrait>() -> T;
}
```

I also have a struct

```
struct MyStruct<T: OtherTrait> {...}
```

I'd like to bind the generic type from `MyStruct` to `generic_method` when implementing the trait.

Something like

```
impl<T: OtherTrait> MyTrait for MyStruct<T> {
    fn generic_method() -> T {...}
}
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I am not too good with rust but couldn't you also do `fn generic_method<T>()`?

Comment: The current definition of `MyTrait` requires an implementation of `generic_method` to work for any `T` defined by the caller. This `T` needs to be moved to the scope of that trait, either as a parameter type or as an associated type.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53085395/1233251

Comment: I tried all the suggestions: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d6db57b37afed1cb140294a0665a210e

I don't think it will compile without changing `MyTrait`

Comment: Yes, you'll have to change the trait if `.generic_method()` actually returns a specific, non-generic type determined by the implementer. Here's your trait using an associated type: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=03253aedddcedf1b9653afe1d4c27a2b