# Generic function over collections of numbers

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I'm trying to compare elements of structs using the [assert_approx_eq!](https://crates.io/crates/assert_approx_eq) macro. The structs I'm working on are

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct Matrix3D {
    n: [[f64; 3]; 3],
}

#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct Vector3D {
    pub x: f64,
    pub y: f64,
    pub z: f64,
}
```

I've implemented the `IntoIterator` trait for both types with the help of a separate iterator struct

```
impl IntoIterator for Matrix3D {
    type Item = f64;
    type IntoIter = Matrix3DIterator;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        Matrix3DIterator {
            n: self.n,
            index: 0,
        }
    }
}

pub struct Matrix3DIterator {
    n: [[f64; 3]; 3],
    index: usize,
}

impl Iterator for Matrix3DIterator {
    type Item = f64;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let i = self.index / 3;
        let j = self.index % 3;
        if i < 3 && j < 3 {
            self.index += 1;
            Some(self.n[j][i])
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

```
impl IntoIterator for Vector3D {
    type Item = f64;
    type IntoIter = Vector3DIterator;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        Vector3DIterator { x: self.x, y: self.y, z: self.z, index: 0}
    }
}

pub struct Vector3DIterator {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
    z: f64,
    index: usize,
}

impl Iterator for Vector3DIterator {
    type Item = f64;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let result = match self.index {
            0 => Some(self.x),
            1 => Some(self.y),
            2 => Some(self.z),
            _ => None
        };
       self.index += 1; 
       result
    }
}
```

When writing tests for these structs I made a helper function that iterates over them and compares each element. I'm struggling to express this is a generic way such that I can use the same function to compare two matrices or two vectors with each other. Specifically, the type of the collection must support the subtraction operation and implement an `abs` function for the `assert_approx_eq!` macro. What I've got so far is

```
use num_traits::Float;
fn elementwise_approx_comparison<I: IntoIterator>(result: I, expected: I) -> () 
    where I::Item: Float,
          I::Item: std::fmt::Debug {
        for (r, e) in std::iter::zip(result, expected) {
            assert_approx_eq!(r, e);
        }
    }
```

which gives the following error

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/matrix.rs:411:13
    |
411 |             assert_approx_eq!(r, e);
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected associated type, found floating-point number
    |
    = note: expected associated type `<I as IntoIterator>::Item`
                          found type `{float}`
    = note: this error originates in the macro `assert_approx_eq` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
help: consider constraining the associated type `<I as IntoIterator>::Item` to `{float}`
    |
407 |     fn elementwise_approx_comparison<I: IntoIterator<Item = {float}>>(result: I, expected: I) -> () 
    |                                                     ++++++++++++++++
```

What does it mean that the compiler expected an associated type but found floating-point number instead? How do I express that the function `elementwise_approx_comparison` should accept a collection `I` that can be made into an iterator, and iterates over (in this case) floating type numbers?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53085270/how-do-i-implement-a-trait-with-a-generic-method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551177/expected-type-parameter-error-in-the-constructor-of-a-generic-struct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `assert_approx_eq` tries to compare the difference between the two values and a literal constant, but Rust doesn't know how to unify the type of this literal constant with the actual type of the values. However `assert_approx_eq` allows you to specify the comparison threshold, and `Float` defines an [`epsilon()`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/0.2.15/num_traits/float/trait.Float.html#method.epsilon) method that gives you a "small positive value" suitable for this kind of use. Therefore you can do:

```
use num_traits::Float;
fn elementwise_approx_comparison<I: IntoIterator>(result: I, expected: I) -> () 
    where I::Item: Float,
          I::Item: std::fmt::Debug 
{
    for (r, e) in std::iter::zip(result, expected) {
        assert_approx_eq!(r, e, Float::epsilon());
    }
}
```

or if `f32::EPSILON` is too small for you, you can use `Float::from` to specify the threshold yourself:

```
use num_traits::Float;
fn elementwise_approx_comparison<I: IntoIterator>(result: I, expected: I) -> () 
    where I::Item: Float,
          I::Item: std::fmt::Debug 
{
    for (r, e) in std::iter::zip(result, expected) {
        assert_approx_eq!(r, e, Float::from(1e-6f32));
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that epsilon is the machine epsilon which is undesirable for this case.

Comment: @attempt0 Could you elaborate on why this is undesirable in this case?

Comment: @SimonCarlson if you use it on `f32` inputs, `assert_approx_eq!(x, y, f32::EPSILON)` it the same as `assert_eq!(x, y)` since the difference can only be smaller than `EPSILON` if it is exactly zero. For `f64` it's all right since `Float::epsilon()` uses `f32::EPSILON` for all types.

Comment: Of course @attempt0's comment doesn't apply to my second example since I added it after he commented.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the macro uses a floating point number in the definition. You can additionally require the type to be comparable to f64. However this effectively restrict the type to be f64 which is not ideal.

```rs
fn elementwise_approx_comparison<I: IntoIterator>(result: I, expected: I) -> ()
where
    <I as IntoIterator>::Item: Float + PartialOrd<f64>,
    I::Item: std::fmt::Debug,
{
    for (r, e) in std::iter::zip(result, expected) {
        assert_approx_eq!(r, e);
    }
}
```

Another solution would be to require the caller to construct the epsilon for the function.

```rs
fn elementwise_approx_comparison<I: IntoIterator<Item = F>, F: Float>(
    result: I,
    expected: I,
    eps: F,
) -> ()
where
    I::Item: std::fmt::Debug,
{
    for (r, e) in std::iter::zip(result, expected) {
        assert_approx_eq!(r, e, eps);
    }
}
```