# Extending Iterator over pairs with map_keys

Tags: rust, iterator

I'm trying to write some simple extension methods for Rust's `Iterator` when it's iterating over `(K, V)` pairs. The simplest implementation I can come up with for mapping keys involves reusing [`Iterator::map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map) like so:

```
use std::iter::Map;

trait KeyedIterator<K, V>: Iterator<Item = (K, V)> {
    fn map_keys<R, F, G>(self, f: F) -> Map<Self, G>
    where
        Self: Sized,
        F: FnMut(K) -> R,
        G: FnMut((K, V)) -> (R, V),
    {
        self.map(|(key, value): (K, V)| (f(key), value))
    }
}

impl<I, K, V> KeyedIterator<K, V> for I where I: Iterator<Item = (K, V)> {}
```

However, it has this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:10:18
   |
10 |         self.map(|(key, value): (K, V)| (f(key), value))
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter, found closure
   |
   = note: expected type `G`
              found type `[closure@src/lib.rs:10:18: 10:56 f:_]`
```

Shouldn't the closure implement `G` as it is a function from `(K, V)` to `(R, V)`? What am I missing here?

Comment: What is your `Map`?

Comment: @Boiethios: It's the standard library [`core::iter::Map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/iter/struct.Map.html) returned by [`Iterator#map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map)

Comment: `G` is a type parameter of `map_keys`, so it must be determined by the _caller_ of `map_keys`. But your code is determining it from inside that function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you declare a type parameter for a type or a function, that type must be provided by the *caller*. However, in your code, you are attempting to determine the type `G` in the body of `map_keys`, based on the type of the closure that is defined there.

Usually, the way to have a function body determine a type is with an existential return type (e.g. `Map<Self, impl FnMut((K, V)) -> (R, V)>`. However, this is not permitted in trait methods.

The pattern that is used for all the built-in iterator adapters will work for your use case though. That is, define a struct, which is returned by your method and make it an iterator:

```
// Struct to hold the state of the iterator
struct KeyedIter<I, F> {
    iter: I,
    f: F,
}

// Make KeyedIter an iterator whenever `I` is an iterator over tuples and `F` has the 
// correct signature
impl<K, V, R, I, F> Iterator for KeyedIter<I, F>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = (K, V)>,
    F: FnMut(K) -> R,
{
    type Item = R;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.iter.next().map(|(k, _v)| (self.f)(k))
    }
}

// A trait for adding the `map_keys` method
trait KeyedIterator<K, V> {
    fn map_keys<R, F>(self, f: F) -> KeyedIter<Self, F>
    where
        F: FnMut(K) -> R,
        Self: Sized;
}

// implement the trait for all iterators over tuples
impl<I, K, V> KeyedIterator<K, V> for I
where
    I: Iterator<Item = (K, V)>,
{
    fn map_keys<R, F>(self, f: F) -> KeyedIter<Self, F>
    where
        F: FnMut(K) -> R,
        Self: Sized,
    {
        KeyedIter { iter: self, f }
    }
}
```

The `KeyedIter` struct is parameterised by types that the caller knows about: the previous iterator, and the mapping function. There is no need to try to express the type of an intermediate closure - instead it's handled lazily in the iterator's `next()` method.

---

See also:

- ["Expected type parameter" error in the constructor of a generic struct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32551408/493729)

Comment: Ah, this makes sense to me now! Re: the no existential return types in traits, do you know if this is an intrinsic problem that is unlikely to ever be possible or something that simply hasn't been implemented yet?

Comment: Answering my own question, this may be possible in the future: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1522-conservative-impl-trait.md

Comment: It certainly would make the trait non-object-safe. Traits don't _need_ to be object-safe of course, and I can't see any other theoretical problems with it. I definitely could be wrong on that point though!

Answer (score 0):

`G` is tied by the method and abstracts over the concrete type being passed in for each function call. For example:

```
fn print<T: core::fmt::Debug>(t: T) {
    println!("{:?}", t);
}

fn main() {
    print(1);
    print(1f64);
    print("1");
}
```

This means that it is not possible to return an arbitrary **fixed** `G` implementation but there are some workarounds.

1 - Static dispatch. The code must be modified to receive and return the same generic:

```
use core::iter::Map;

trait KeyedIterator<K, V>: Iterator<Item = (K, V)> {
    fn map_keys<R, F>(self, f: F) -> Map<Self, F>
    where
        Self: Sized,
        F: FnMut((K, V)) -> (R, V),
    {
        self.map(f)
    }
}

impl<I, K, V> KeyedIterator<K, V> for I where I: Iterator<Item = (K, V)> {}

fn main() {
    let vec = vec![(1u32, 2i32), (3, 4), (5, 6)];
    println!("{:?}", vec.into_iter().map_keys(|(k, v)| (k as f64 + 0.8, v)).collect::<Vec<(f64, i32)>>());
}
```

2 - Dynamic dispatch. With a little of run-time overhead, you can use `Box`.

```
trait KeyedIterator<K, V>: Iterator<Item = (K, V)> {
    fn map_keys<'a, R, F: 'a>(self, mut f: F) -> Box<Iterator<Item = (R, V)> + 'a>
    where
        Self: Sized + 'a,
        F: FnMut(K) -> R
    {
        Box::new(self.map(move |(key, value): (K, V)| (f(key), value)))
    }
}

impl<I, K, V> KeyedIterator<K, V> for I where
    I: Iterator<Item = (K, V)> {}

fn main() {
    let vec = vec![(1u32, 2i32), (3, 4), (5, 6)];
    println!(
        "{:?}",
        vec.into_iter()
            .map_keys(|k| k as f64 + 0.8)
            .collect::<Vec<(f64, i32)>>()
    );
}
```