# How can I return something meaningful from a generic function if there is nothing to return?

Tags: rust, serde-json

I'm building a library in Rust that has a `send` method that performs HTTP requests against a local RPC server using reqwest.

This method returns a generic type `R` in a `Result` where `R: DeserializeOwned`. After making the correct types for every response, `serde_json::from_str()` can get me the type.

If there is no response upon a request, how can I make `send` still return something meaningful?

This is the code I have now:

```
fn send<R, T>(
    &self,
    request: &RpcRequest<T>,
) -> Result<R, ApiError>
    where
        T: Serialize + Debug,
        R: DeserializeOwned + Debug,
```

```
let res = serde_json::from_str(&buf).map_err(|err| ClientError::Json(err))
```

I am now forced to create and return an `Err`, but technically, the request returning no response is expected behavior, so I want to return something other than an `Err`.

I tried to work around this by wrapping `R` with `Option`, but that means I have to double unwrap every response, and 98% of the responses from reqwest do have data in their response, so it feels a bit like overkill.

I also tried to return a self-made `EmptyResponse` type, but the compiler complains: `expected type R, found type EmptyResponse`. I think returning a type `EmptyResponse` would be what I want, but maybe someone can shed some tips on how to maybe do this even better.

Comment: *I think returning a type `EmptyResponse` would be what I want* — this is impossible: [“Expected type parameter” error in the constructor of a generic struct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551177/155423).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. When you make the request (call `send`), do you know in advance whether the response (if successful) will contain data or not? Or do you make the request not knowing whether an `R` will actually be returned?

Comment: I know beforehand what types will be returned, either the type I want or an Err. Even for the request where a success returns nothing, an error will return a JSON with error message.

Comment: Does `send<(), _>` work? If the caller knows it's expecting "nothing", then it shouldn't tell `send` to deserialize to "something"

Answer (score 1):

You can return an `Result<Option<R>, ApiError>` as shown in [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/error/multiple_error_types/option_result.html), then match it like this:

```rust
match sender.send(request) {
    Ok(Some(r)) => {
        // process response
    }
    Ok(None) => {
        // process empty response
    }
    Err(e) => {
        // process error
    }
}
// or
if let Ok(Some(r)) = sender.send(request) {
    // process response
}
```

> I tried to work around this by wrapping `R` with `Option`, but that means I have to double unwrap every response, and 98% of the responses from reqwest do have data in their response, so it feels a bit like overkill.

Unwrapping the `Option` is a very cheap operation, there's nothing to be worried about.

Comment: That `if let` without an `else` is only really OK when you want to just ignore errors and continue, which shouldn't be most of the time. I'd expect `.unwrap()` (panicking) or `?` (propagating the error up the call stack) to be more generally useful.

Comment: I don't think OP is worried about the performance of unwrapping twice but the **ergonomics**. Your proposed solution requires *every call site* to have 6 or so extra lines of boilerplate. In "98% of the responses", the empty response will be treated as an error, duplicating code everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The pragmatic answer is to have two functions:

```
fn send<R, T>(&self, request: &RpcRequest<T>) -> Result<R, ApiError>
where
    T: Serialize + Debug,
    R: DeserializeOwned + Debug,
```

```
fn send_no_response<T>(&self, request: &RpcRequest<T>) -> Result<(), ApiError>
where
    T: Serialize + Debug,
```

---

*If* your server happens to return a value that can be deserialized into the type  `()`, then you can avoid the overhead of two functions. However, this is **not** the case for JSON, one of the most common formats:

```
use serde::de::DeserializeOwned; // 1.0.85
use serde_json; // 1.0.37

type Error = Box<std::error::Error>;
type Result<T, E = Error> = std::result::Result<T, E>;

fn send<R>() -> Result<R, Error>
where
    R: DeserializeOwned,
{
    serde_json::from_str("").map_err(Into::into)
}

fn main() {
    let _r: () = send().expect("Unable to deserialize");
}
```

This panics:

```
Unable to deserialize: Error("EOF while parsing a value", line: 1, column: 0)
```

---

In a world with specialization, you can use it and a helper trait to reduce back to one function:

```
#![feature(specialization)]

use serde::de::DeserializeOwned; // 1.0.85
use serde_json; // 1.0.37

type Error = Box<std::error::Error>;
type Result<T, E = Error> = std::result::Result<T, E>;

type ApiResponse = &'static str;

trait FromApi: Sized {
    fn convert(response: ApiResponse) -> Result<Self, Error>;
}

impl<R> FromApi for R
where
    R: DeserializeOwned,
{
    default fn convert(response: ApiResponse) -> Result<R, Error> {
        eprintln!("deserializing the response");
        serde_json::from_str(response).map_err(Into::into)
    }
}

impl FromApi for () {
    fn convert(_response: ApiResponse) -> Result<Self, Error> {
        eprintln!("Ignoring the response");
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn send<R: FromApi>() -> Result<R> {
    eprintln!(r#""sending" the request"#);
    let api_response = "";
    R::convert(api_response)
}

fn main() {
    let _r: () = send().expect("Unable to deserialize");
}
```