# Is there any way to convert a String to a enum with fields (a named struct enum)?

Tags: generics, enums, rust

I have a `HashMap<String, serde_json::Value>`, and I want to convert it into `HashMap<String, Attribute>`. I want to convert a field to an `Attribute` based on the name (with a value):

```rust
pub struct Name {
    pub first_name: String,
    pub last_name: String,
}

pub enum Attribute {
    __Noop,
    Name(Name),
    Age(i32),
    Id(String),
}

impl Attribute {
    fn new<T>(field_name: &str, attrs: T) -> Attribute {
        if field_name == "name" {
            Attribute::Name(attrs)
        } else if field_name == "age" {
            Attribute::Age(attrs)
        } else if field_name == "id" {
            Attribute::Id(attrs)
        } else {
            Attribute::__Noop
        }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [“Expected type parameter” error in the constructor of a generic struct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551177/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense in your context; directly deserialize to an `Account` instead of using a `serde_json::Value`. Also, your code doesn't appear rational; what should happen if someone calls `new("id", false)`? How would the boolean become an ID?