# How to construct a concrete type in a generic function?

Tags: function, generics, rust, traits

With what would I need to replace `/* type */` so that `o_f` could equal `None`, `Some(a)`, `Some(b)`, or `Some(/* a different function with the same signature */)`?

```
fn func<T: Copy + Ord>(x: &mut Option<Box<Node<T>>>)
{
    let mut o_f: /* type */ = None;
    let mut result_of_f: Option<bool> = None;
    let mut o_b_n_num = Some(Box::new(Node::new(1)));

    // ...

    if let Some(f) = o_f
    {
        result_of_f = Some(f(x) && f(&mut o_b_n_num));
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: `Option<fn (x: &mut Option<Box<Node<T>>>) -> bool>`

Comment: @Jmb `Option<fn (x: &mut Option<Box<Node<T>>>) -> bool>` would indeed be correct if not for the call `f(&mut o_b_n_num)`, because `1` is not of type `T`.

Comment: Well then `Option<fn (x: &mut Option<Box<Node<i32>>>) -> bool>`

Comment: @Jmb what I'm getting at is this: is there a way to annotate `f` so that, in different places, it can be called on values of *different* `Option<Box<Node<...>>>` types, as long as those types satisfy the `Copy + Ord` constraint described in the signatures of `a` and `b`?

Comment: No, a variable can only have a single type. You can however redefine a variable, so you can add a new `let o_f = …` when you need a different type for it.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is not possible. You have a function generic over `T` but internally you're trying to use concrete type `i32`. Rust monomorphizes generic functions based on what types they get called with. Take this program for example:

```rust
fn func<F, T>(f: F, t: T)
    where F: Fn(T)
{
    f(t);
}

struct S;
struct R;

fn main() {
    func(|x| {}, S);
    func(|x| {}, R);
}
```

Will get compiled to something like:

```rust
fn func_S(f: impl Fn(S), s: S)
{
    f(s);
}

fn func_R(f: impl Fn(R), r: R)
{
    f(r);
}

struct S;
struct R;

fn main() {
    func_S(|s| {}, S);
    func_R(|r| {}, R);
}
```

Which is all well and good, but what if we go back and change the first function to this (which is essentially what you're trying to do):

```rust
fn func<F, T>(f: F, t: T)
    where F: Fn(T)
{
    f(t);
    f(1); // concrete type i32, not type T
}

struct S;
struct R;

fn main() {
    func(|x| {}, S);
    func(|x| {}, R);
}
```

Now it wouldn't compile, but if we imagined it did then it'd like something like this:

```rust
fn func_S(f: impl Fn(S), s: S)
{
    f(s);
    f(1); // error! f expects S not i32
}

fn func_R(f: impl Fn(R), r: R)
{
    f(r);
    f(1); // error! f expects R not i32
}

struct S;
struct R;

fn main() {
    func_S(|s| {}, S);
    func_R(|r| {}, R);
}
```

You see how that makes no sense at all? You're trying to pass a `i32` to functions that expect `S` and `R`.

Now, you have a couple options. If you want some data structure of just `i32`s then you don't need to make it generic and can define it just for `i32`s. If you want a generic structure where, if some node is missing, and you want populate it with a "default" node (perhaps in the case of `Node<i32>` that default node is `Node::new(1)`) then you can bind `T` on `Default` and write something like this:

```rust
#[derive(Default)]
struct Node<T: Default>(T);

#[derive(Default)]
struct S;
#[derive(Default)]
struct R;

fn func<F, T>(f: F, t: Option<Node<T>>)
    where T: Default, F: Fn(Node<T>)
{
    f(t.unwrap_or_default());
}

fn main() {
    func(|x| {}, Some(Node(S)));
    func(|x| {}, Some(Node(R)));
    func(|x: Node<i32>| {}, None);
}
```

Now your function is truly generic over `T` and handles the case of all `Node<T>` including `Node<i32>`.

See also

- [“Expected type parameter” error in the constructor of a generic struct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551177/2766908)