# I have a problem with a generic function and enum

Tags: rust

I have a problem with a generic function ([Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=00f985ac00c0569568d5765b00806932)):

```
use core::any::Any;
use std::fmt;
use std::fmt::Debug;

type BoolPtr = Box<dyn Fn(String, bool) -> Result<(), String>>;
type U8Ptr = Box<dyn Fn(String, u8) -> Result<(), String>>;
type U16Ptr = Box<dyn Fn(String, u8) -> Result<(), String>>;

pub enum WriteCallbackClosure {
    BOOL(BoolPtr),
    U8(U8Ptr),
    U16(U16Ptr),
}

pub fn create_cb_enum<T, Closure>(
    var_name: &String,
    var_type: &String,
    callback: Closure,
) -> Option<WriteCallbackClosure>
where
    Closure: 'static + Sized + std::panic::UnwindSafe + std::panic::RefUnwindSafe + Send + Sync,
    T: Any,
    Closure: Fn(String, T) -> Result<(), String>,
{
    let box_cb = Box::new(callback);

    if var_name == "BOOL" {
        return Some(WriteCallbackClosure::BOOL(box_cb));
    } else if var_name == "U8" {
        return Some(WriteCallbackClosure::U8(box_cb));
    }

    return None;
}

fn main() {
    let f1 = move |name, state: bool| {
        println!("name: {}, state: {}", name, state);
        return Ok(());
    };

    let v1 = create_cb_enum(&"v1_bool".to_string(), &"BOOL".to_string(), f1);

    let f2 = move |name, state: u8| {
        println!("name: {}, state: {}", name, state);
        return Ok(());
    };

    let v2 = create_cb_enum(&"v2_u8".to_string(), &"U8".to_string(), f2);
}
```

The compiler suggests:

```
error[E0277]: expected a `std::ops::Fn<(std::string::String, bool)>` closure, found `Closure`
  --> src/main.rs:28:48
   |
28 |         return Some(WriteCallbackClosure::BOOL(box_cb));
   |                                                ^^^^^^ expected an `Fn<(std::string::String, bool)>` closure, found `Closure`
   |
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn std::ops::Fn(std::string::String, bool) -> std::result::Result<(), std::string::String>`
help: consider further restricting type parameter `Closure`
   |
23 |     Closure: Fn(String, T) -> Result<(), String>, Closure: std::ops::Fn<(std::string::String, bool)>
   |                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0277]: expected a `std::ops::Fn<(std::string::String, u8)>` closure, found `Closure`
  --> src/main.rs:30:46
   |
30 |         return Some(WriteCallbackClosure::U8(box_cb));
   |                                              ^^^^^^ expected an `Fn<(std::string::String, u8)>` closure, found `Closure`
   |
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn std::ops::Fn(std::string::String, u8) -> std::result::Result<(), std::string::String>`
help: consider further restricting type parameter `Closure`
   |
23 |     Closure: Fn(String, T) -> Result<(), String>, Closure: std::ops::Fn<(std::string::String, u8)>
   |                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It's weird because `function` is a generic called `Closure`: `Fn(String, T) -> Result<(), String>`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? This code is clearly unsound, look e. g. at `create_cb_enum<bool,...>("U8", ...)`. Are you maybe looking for the [Any](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html) trait?

Comment: @L.Riemer the `Any` trait is the very first line of code in the example OP has provided.

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [“Expected type parameter” error in the constructor of a generic struct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551177/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: @Shepmaster Excuse me for not seeing this, perhaps this was due to the trait not being used to actually do anything in the provided snippet, apart from a seemingly unnecessary bound. I'll take a closer look next time.

Comment: @L.Riemer no worries. I'm not sure what it is about this specific piece of code, but I also find it very hard to read for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated to reflect non-static Fn** (see original answer below)

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=df524a4a104fc72f09d16a688d730dcb)

```
type BoolPtr<'a> = Box<dyn 'a + FnMut(String, bool) -> Result<(), String>>;
type U8Ptr<'a> = Box<dyn 'a + FnMut(String, u8) -> Result<(), String>>;
type U16Ptr<'a> = Box<dyn 'a + FnMut(String, u16) -> Result<(), String>>;

pub enum WriteCallbackClosure<'a>
{
    BOOL(BoolPtr<'a>),
    U8(U8Ptr<'a>),
    U16(U16Ptr<'a>),
}

trait WriteCallbackCreatorTrait<T> {
    fn from_fn<'a, P> (v: P) -> Option<WriteCallbackClosure<'a>> 
    where P: 'a + Sized + FnMut(String, T) -> Result<(), String>;
}

impl WriteCallbackCreatorTrait<bool> for WriteCallbackClosure<'_> {
    fn from_fn<'a, P>(v: P) -> Option<WriteCallbackClosure<'a>> 
    where P: 'a + Sized + FnMut(String, bool) -> Result<(), String>
    {
        
        let boxed = Box::new(v);
        let closure = WriteCallbackClosure::BOOL(boxed);
        return Some(closure);
    }
}


impl WriteCallbackCreatorTrait<u8> for WriteCallbackClosure<'_> {
    fn from_fn<'a, P>(v: P) -> Option<WriteCallbackClosure<'a>> 
    where P: 'a + Sized + FnMut(String, u8) -> Result<(), String>
    {
        let boxed = Box::new(v);
        let closure = WriteCallbackClosure::U8(boxed);
        return Some(closure);
    }
}

impl WriteCallbackCreatorTrait<u16> for WriteCallbackClosure<'_> {
    fn from_fn<'a, P>(v: P) -> Option<WriteCallbackClosure<'a>>
    where P: 'a + Sized + FnMut(String, u16) -> Result<(), String>
    {
        let boxed = Box::new(v);
        let closure = WriteCallbackClosure::U16(boxed);
        return Some(closure);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut my_state = false;
    
    let f1 = |name, state: bool| {
        println!("name: {}, state: {}", name, state);
        my_state = state;
        return Ok(());
    };
          
    let _v1 = WriteCallbackClosure::from_fn(f1);
    

}
```

**Original answer**

It looks like you're looking for something like this ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d5d00466bf8caff6b439e3f2345d5baa))

```
type BoolPtr = Box<dyn Fn(String, bool) -> Result<(), String>>;
type U8Ptr = Box<dyn Fn(String, u8) -> Result<(), String>>;
type U16Ptr = Box<dyn Fn(String, u16) -> Result<(), String>>;

pub enum WriteCallbackClosure
{
    BOOL(BoolPtr),
    U8(U8Ptr),
    U16(U16Ptr),
}

trait WriteCallbackCreatorTrait<T> {
    fn from_fn<P> (v: P) -> Option<WriteCallbackClosure> 
    where P: 'static + Sized + Fn(String, T) -> Result<(), String>;
}

impl WriteCallbackCreatorTrait<bool> for WriteCallbackClosure {
    fn from_fn<P>(v: P) -> Option<WriteCallbackClosure> 
    where P: 'static + Sized + Fn(String, bool) -> Result<(), String>
    {
        let boxed = Box::new(v);
        let closure = WriteCallbackClosure::BOOL(boxed);
        return Some(closure);
    }
}

impl WriteCallbackCreatorTrait<u8> for WriteCallbackClosure {
    fn from_fn<P>(v: P) -> Option<WriteCallbackClosure> 
    where P: 'static + Sized + Fn(String, u8) -> Result<(), String>
    {
        let boxed = Box::new(v);
        let closure = WriteCallbackClosure::U8(boxed);
        return Some(closure);
    }
}

impl WriteCallbackCreatorTrait<u16> for WriteCallbackClosure {
    fn from_fn<P>(v: P) -> Option<WriteCallbackClosure>
    where P: 'static + Sized + Fn(String, u16) -> Result<(), String>
    {
        let boxed = Box::new(v);
        let closure = WriteCallbackClosure::U16(boxed);
        return Some(closure);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let f1 = move |name, state: bool| {
        println!("name: {}, state: {}", name, state);
        return Ok(());
    };
    
    let _v1 = WriteCallbackClosure::from_fn(f1);
    
    let f2 = move |name, state: u8| {
        println!("name: {}, state: {}", name, state);
        return Ok(());
    };
    
    let _v2 = WriteCallbackClosure::from_fn(f2);
}
```

The original `create_cb_enum` doesn't specify the particular type for Closure's second parameter.

Comment: Thx for reply.
I would like change Fn() to FnMut() in your example.
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=278895059599fea33f3468ce83eb073f

Comment: @MichałHanusek, here we go https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=df524a4a104fc72f09d16a688d730dcb