# How can I bind a struct's generic type so that it is a concrete type for an associated function?

Tags: generics, rust

I'm implementing a struct in which one of the functions access data from a vector of strings. Is there a way to bind a generic type so that it is always a `String` just for this single function? For example:

```rust
impl<T> MyStruct<T> {
    // How can I restrict that T is String just for this function.
    fn my_function(&self) -> Vec<T> {}

    // ... some other functions
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the concrete type instead of the generic:

```rust
impl MyStruct<String> {
    fn my_function(&self) -> Vec<String> {}
}
```

See also:

- ["Expected type parameter" error in the constructor of a generic struct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551177/155423)